# Please add a link to the Meta MSE MathJax tutorial to the editing help

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, new-users

If you're asking a question and you click the help button, it will send you to the Editing Help page, which has a [LaTeX section](https://physics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) that looks like this:

> [image]

This is a perfect place to have a link to [the Meta MSE tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) we use elsewhere, but there's currently no such link. Can we add one?

Comment: Just noting that this will have to be done by the SE team; mods can't edit that page.

Comment: @DavidZ Sure, but we need a consensus here before they do, right? ;-).

Comment: Probably. Though I don't think this is quite as big a deal as, say, getting a tag burninated, so the bar for consensus might not be as high.

Comment: Given the downvotes, apparently some people disagree - can you clarify why?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I can't see any reason for them. Sincere condolences.

Comment: I suppose not everyone is aware of the meaning of votes for a feature request.